# Accessibility issue for scrollable content

Tags: javascript, html, css, nvda

When the focus is coming on scrollable content all content is announcing without an aria label.

I want to announce only the aria labels when the focus comes on scrollable content.

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 500px; overflow: auto;" tabindex="0" aria-label="scroll to content">
  <div class="MuiGrid-root-60 MuiGrid-item-62 MuiGrid-grid-xs-12-106 MuiGrid-grid-sm-12-120 MuiGrid-grid-lg-12-148">
    <div class="MuiPaper-root-20 MuiCard-root-543 product-box-bundle-card bundle-card multipack-tout horizontal-view MuiPaper-elevation1-24 MuiPaper-rounded-21">
      <div class="product-content-wrapper"><button class="MuiButtonBase-root-202 MuiButton-root-175 MuiButton-text-177 media-card-wrapper" tabindex="-1" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label-176"><img alt="Balaji wafers" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRezk0eYUUz0AnzUUbpx8HGJlSDUADjpix21A&usqp=CAU"></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-277"></span></button>
        <div
          class="product-information">
          <div class="product-heading">Masala Masti Potato Chips</div>
          <div class="product-action">
            <div class="quantity-count-contain">
              <div class="quantity-count-wrapper"><input type="text" id="cartproductListInput10649700" disabled="" tabindex="0" value="5"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="MuiGrid-root-60 MuiGrid-item-62 MuiGrid-grid-xs-12-106 MuiGrid-grid-sm-12-120 MuiGrid-grid-lg-12-148">
  <div class="MuiPaper-root-20 MuiCard-root-543 product-box-bundle-card bundle-card multipack-tout horizontal-view MuiPaper-elevation1-24 MuiPaper-rounded-21">
    <div class="product-content-wrapper"><button class="MuiButtonBase-root-202 MuiButton-root-175 MuiButton-text-177 media-card-wrapper" tabindex="-1" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label-176"><img alt="Balaji wafers" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRezk0eYUUz0AnzUUbpx8HGJlSDUADjpix21A&usqp=CAU"></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-277"></span></button>
      <div
        class="product-information">
        <div class="product-heading">Masala Masti Potato Chips</div>
        <div class="product-action">
          <div class="quantity-count-contain">
            <div class="quantity-count-wrapper"><input type="text" id="cartproductListInput10649700" disabled="" tabindex="0" value="5"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show us some cade of what you tried

Comment: @Saren this is the code snippet for what I have tried.
https://codepen.io/rahulFront/pen/JjNmPYE